# How to broadcast live video from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, live-streaming

I want to develop iPhone application to broadcast live video to web. Ustream has application that broadcast from iPhone to web.

Any suggestion?
Which API I should use?
Which Media media sever should I use?

Thanks,
Adil

Comment: You have to use a third party lib for that like [ANGL streaming lib](http://angl.tv/lib/).

Answer (score 1):

For live streaming we have to use HTTP streaming or RTMP Streaming with wowza MEdia server here we have to give the host address with port number (by default port number is 1935).
here is the some useful link i have used in my application
http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/ios/index.html?asyncall.htm
you can also find demo apps from github here is the link
https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos/downloads

Comment: this library is of 5000 USD

Answer (score 1):

You can use StreamingVideoProvider video platform and their iOS app to stream live video directly from iOS device iPhone or iPad. More info [here](http://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/ezecaster-mobile.html).

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve frames for the video using AVCaptureSession and send each frame to to Server.
Please Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601041/942966)