# Is it necessary to broadcast video using http live streaming

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, http-live-streaming

I am making an app from which user can broadcast live video and other user can watch.
When user will broadcast video then will upstream video to dacast server.Using streaming link other user can watch video.
I read apple documentation

> Requirements for Apps Warning: iOS apps submitted for distribution in
>   the App Store must conform to these requirements.
>
> If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video
>   exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute
>   period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming. (Progressive
>   download may be used for smaller clips.)
>
> If your app uses HTTP Live Streaming over cellular networks, you are
>   required to provide at least one stream at 64 Kbps or lower bandwidth
>   (the low-bandwidth stream may be audio-only or audio with a still
>   image).
>
> These requirements apply to iOS apps submitted for distribution in the
>   App Store for use on Apple products. Non-compliant apps may be
>   rejected or removed, at the discretion of Apple.

From documentation it is clear that while watching live streaming video(from server to app) **http live streaming** is important.
But it is not clear for me whether they are asking even to upstream(from app to server dacast) video should be transferred using **http live streaming** protocol ?

Or I can use **rtsp** or **rtmp** protocol to upstream video to server ?

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to use any protocol to upload a video.

You can even use HTTP if needed!

I have used AFNetworking in multiple Applications to upload.

Check this link to see how to upload via AFNetworking --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/20089540/3059302

For live upstreaming, you can use any framework necessary. Check this --> [How to broadcast live video from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078067/how-to-broadcast-live-video-from-iphone)

Kickflip *https://kickflip.io*  does not use HTTP live streaming for uploading and is popularly used by many developers, hence I guess its safe to use anything else apart from HTTP Live Stream.

Also, not sure if you can really upload using HTTP Live stream, its not a part of their protocol.

Comment: actually it is not uploading video.User while recording video from iphone camera they will upstream video to dacast server.