# Capture video on iOS device and live stream it to a server (or another mobile)

Tags: ios, video, streaming, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I want to be able to record footage using my iOS device and stream it directly to a server.

There's quite a few articles on S.O. that talk about this, but I'm not sure any have answered the question very well.

Should I be using HTTP Live Streaming, or is this just for sending data *to* an iPhone?
Should I be using AVCaptureSession to grab the video (a segment at a time?), sending each segment to the server?
Should I be using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and ffmpeg for streaming?

I'm a little lost with all this, so any sample code or docs or links would be really appreciated.

Thanks for your help guys.

Duncan

Comment: The ffmpeg license is not compatible with apps published via the iTunes AppStore.  The HTTP live streaming protocol is better suited to stored content, not streaming live content.

Comment: Please follow this link, [Upload live streaming video from iPhone like Ustream or Qik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960782/upload-live-streaming-video-from-iphone-like-ustream-or-qik)

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a network protocol for that purpose and find an appropriate media server to receive and process the stream. If the RTMP format is ok for your project, check [angl library](http://angl.tv/lib/) which supports RTMP streaming from iOS. Currently it's compatible with iOS 6 and 7.