# Live streaming from the iPhone to a website

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I'm currently trying to make an app, that'll let me live stream what the iPhones camera see's and then have this live stream visible on my website, however I'm unsure on what i need to do on both server side and iOS side.

Do i need to set anything up on my web server to be able to receive this, or is it possible to do it all on the iPhone?

Also what is the best way of sending the video and audio to the site, i read in the documentation it was to do 10 seconds chunks and then have another one overlapping so it's seamless, is this correct or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5601041/409315

Comment: did you implement this?.I need your help