# AVFoundation Capturing Video iOS sdk `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput ` and write on server

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, live-streaming

I Know there are many questions related this topic but not finding reliable solution so that posting new.

Capturing Video with `iOS SDK` using `AVFoundation` framework.

**Steps followed :**

**First Step :**

[image]

**Second Step :**

Assemble the objects (microphone or camera) to represent inputs and outputs, and use an instance of `AVCaptureSession` to coordinate the data flow between them.

- Instance of `AVCaptureDevice` to represent the input device, such as
  a camera or microphone.
- Instance of a concrete subclass of `AVCaptureInput` to configure the ports from the input device
- Instance of a concrete subclass of `AVCaptureOutput` to manage the output to a
  movie file or still image.

**Third Step :**
For Showing the user what a camera is recording, Used the instance of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`

**Issue**

I am looking the Output as Video File, So setting the output as `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and saving movie data to a file like.

```
[aMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:<#The delegate#>];
```

But I want to write this data direct on server(if i try to read this url file while session running showing '0' size.) so that server can perform suitable task so that live Streaming can be achieve.

So is there any way i can read the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` continuously.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601041/1576274

Essentially, you don't want to use AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, you want to use a different subclass of AVCaptureVideoDataOutput like AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.  Then create a delegate to receive buffers from your instance of AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.

Refer to these docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html